# Angular2 Inject Http Without Bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular2-di, angular2-injection

**Context:**

I have a class that is going to form POST requests for my REST Api, lets call it *requester*. Every ajax call made in my app will be sent through this. Thus I don't want to provide Http via `bootstrap(foo, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);` That would make it global and I need it to be injected to *requester*

**Code:**

```
import {Http} from '@angular2/http';
@Injectable()
@Component({providers: [Http]})
export class requester {
    constructor(private http:Http){}
    ...
}
```

**Error:**

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http! (requestor -> Http)

Comment: `@Injectable()` and `@Component()` look weird together. Very likely you have to remove `@Component()` thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it like this

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }
}
```

or use it like this

```
public constructor(@Inject(Http)  private http: Http) {}
```

Comment: I still get the same thing

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular2/http';

    @Component({
          ....
           providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
            ....})
    export class requester {
        constructor(private http:Http){}
        ...
    }
```

Assuming missing providers for your request

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `requester` is a service.

Each `Component` which uses your service `requester` have to reference `HTTP_PROVIDERS`:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular2/http';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, requester],
  ...
})

export class MyComponent{
  constructor(private _req: requester) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Why cant the *requester* be the only one that requires the HTTP_PROVIDER?

Comment: I'm guessing it's somehow related to the way how annotation is converted into metadata for `Injectable` enities. Check more information http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html